# Why to create Scanner as a private

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

what happen if we create scanner as private like

```
private Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in)
```

is it is protected and why?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make it private, itll only be visible in the class that declares it. Google ' Access Modifiers'